# num1 = "3.2, 2.4, 99.8" list1 = tuple(float(i) for i in num1.split(",")) But when I execute it, it shows 'generator' object is not callable

Tags: split, tuples, generator, callable

```
num1 = "3.2, 2.4, 99.8"  
tupl1 = tuple(float(i) for i in num1.split(","))
```

But when I execute it, it shows 'generator' object is not callable.

When using this explanation:

```
num1 = "3.2, 2.4, 99.8"
list1 = list(float(i) for i in num1.split(","))
```

But when I execute it, it works as I plan.
[3.2, 2.4, 99.8]

Could I know the reason. Appreciate the guide.

Comment: I  try in a new jupyter notebook environment, the tuple works. So maybe the problem is caused by the executing enviroment. But I do not know the concrete problem.